# What's the difference between these two printer icons?

Tags: windows-xp, printer, icons, sp3

[image]

Do the different icons represent a different printer driver functionality? And should I be aware of the difference? I never specified anything different in the installation, but the disk makes me concerned that one of these installed printers may be a virtual printer or something...

I am running Windows XP Professional SP3. Also, neither of these printers is set to be the default printer.

Comment: Is there any difference in the text on the icons?

Comment: The text is the same, except for "(Copy 1)" at the end of one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably check the properties to find out for sure, but I would guess that the first icon with the floppy in it is a 'print to file' shortcut. To try it out set it as the default printer open Notepad (or your favorite program), enter a couple of lines and print it.

Comment: I opened the printer properties for both printers. They are both using the same driver, but on two different printer ports. As you said, the one with the disk is on a "Print to File" port, and the other one is on the physical printer port.

Comment: Now that you know what they do, rename the icons to be more descriptive.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps one was created using the **Have Disk...** button while installing. But since you say they were installed using the same method I'm not sure.